# How to save user input in local storage for cordova project

Tags: javascript, input, save

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="ex"></div>
    <input id='sky' name='name'>
    <button onclick="myFunc()">Click me</button>
    <script>
    function myFunc() {
        var ex = document.getElementById('ex');
        var demo = document.getElementById('sky').value;
        var l = localStorage;
        l.saveData = demo;
        console.log(l.saveData);
        console.log('called me');
        ex.innerHTML = l.saveData;
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html
```

how save user input with pure js in my cordova app?
in below code l.saveData saving it but when refreshing it gets unsaved . how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this might be helpful

**Step 1:** Keep your data in local storage. will performing some action

Refer [Localstorage](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.8.0/cordova/storage/localstorage/localstorage.html)

**Step 2:** While refreshing the page retrieve data from local storage if exits